# Debugging 2 separate solution referenced to each other

Tags: c#, debugging, projects-and-solutions

Hi I have 2 different solutions, a web application solution and a service solution.  Each is coded separately in solutions.  The web application is using the generated dll of the service solution as a reference. Now I want to debug both of the solution.  The web application is runned directly in IIS and I know how to debug a web application from IIS without hitting F5, just by attaching the process which is `aspnet_wp.exe`.  For this I can only debug the solution for the web application solution, but I also want to debug the service solution which is in separate solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a WCF service? If so you just have to attach to the host process for the WCF service, and make sure your .pdb is output with your built .dll.

Comment: What would be the host process for the service? this is not a WCF service.  It is just a ASP.NET Webservice but I am not referencing the Webservice but the dll of the provider of the Webservice.

Comment: @I need answers: If you are referencing the DLL from the web application copies the DDL into the bin folder of the web application. Furthermore, in this case you should be able to just set break points in your service code. If you can't maybe it can't find the debug info. Check the bin folder of your web application for the assembly you have referenced (aka the "DLL").

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out somehow but I cannot debug both at the same time, I can just attach the `aspnet_wp.exe` to either of the two solutions. But not on the same time. Maybe there's a better solution for this?